# Is it possible to copy partitioning features from one part to another very similar one in ABAQUS using python scripting? If so, how?

Tags: python, abaqus

[image]

I am quite new at ABAQUS and scripting. I want to copy partitioning features (356 of them) from part A to part B, where part B is very similar to part A except for a few fillet dimensions.
Is this possible?
I have tried copying the features from the .jnl file and changing part and model names. I also added
try and except statements to ignore errors. However, only about 10% of the features in part B are good, the rest of the partitions have to be deleted.

Comment: There is no "ready-to-use" solution, everything depends on your particular problem and its constraints. Please check out [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add more clear examples of what you are trying to achieve and what problems are you facing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not see any problems with my question. What don't you understand?

Comment: Well, for starters, as I've said there is no solution that will work always: partitioning is very geometry-dependant. Generally speaking, if you copy a partition from one thing to another there is no guarantee that it will work. Secondly, you didn't provide any clear example: you are asking about transfer of some partitions of some geometry to some another geometry which is very vague. Last but not least: all these problems arise from the fact that your post is not about some particular thing that works not as expected, but more about a complete solution. For such you usually hire someone.